# querySelectorAll doesn't work with ngInclude, uiView

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to fetch all `<img>` elements inside an element. For this I created a directive 'find-images':

```
app.directive('findImages', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var img_elements = element[0].querySelectorAll('img');
            console.log(img_elements) //doesn't have img elements nested inside ngInclude, uiView
        }
    }
})
```

I used this directive in the body tag like this:

```
<body find-images>
```

However, I am using `ui-router` and in many places `ng-include`(to load nested partials). And the problem I am facing is that **querySelectorAll isn't returning img elements which are nested inside `ng-include` and `ui-view`**. How can I get elements which are nested in them? Also, all nested elements(ui-view, ng-include) are within the body tag.

Comment: when called `link` function for `find-images` _ng-include_ just not load content

Comment: Ok, so how can I wait for those images to be loaded in the directive? Is there some mechanism?

Comment: This seems like an odd use of a directive, perhaps use a service and call as required. The body is most likely only rendered once, so your directive will only run once

Comment: you can try add event handler to document ready, or try [`$viewContentLoaded`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#$viewContentLoaded) event

Comment: @Shaun, once running just _link_ function, but inside, OP can declare something like event handler, or even timer that can running few times

Comment: @Shaun my aim is lazy load images when they are in viewport. For this I was am a directive which will have event handlers for watching if an image comes in the viewport. I ony need the config code to run once. Rest is taken care of the by the event handlers.

Comment: @Grundy thanks I'll try the options.

Comment: I tried 1 or 2 jquery ones and they worked only on page load. I couldn't find any good one in angular so thought about creating one...What approach would you have taken? How would you have gone about creating a lazy loading(images and iframes) reusable component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the logic in the statechangesuccess event fired in ui-router which you could consider the same as page load.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.run(['$document', function ($document) {

 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     var body = $document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     var img_elements = element[body].querySelectorAll('img');
 }

});
```

UPDATE

Another option is to use the onload event raised by ng-include when it is finished rendering.

Also don't forget nginclude is itself a directive, you can use ngswitch in many instances rather than nginclude and render custom directives instead.

That way you have less logic in your controller, and more obvious in the view what is being rendered when.

Comment: what's element[0] here?

Comment: sorry I just copied your code. More supplied. It's just an example. This will run on the body every time (as you were)

Comment: The thing is I want to be able to select the element in which I have to lazy load. It is not body necessarily.

Comment: You were putting the directive on the body, so this is no different, except doesn't require all the events etc. You could use class names to declare whether it required to be processed.

Comment: That was an example. I could have put the directive anywhere I wanted(which I want to achieve!). element[0] then referred to the current element, that is, the element in which I want to lazy load...

Comment: So, then, did you put that directive attribute within the template of whatever is coming in to ng-include? As you describe?

Comment: I can, but there are a lot of templates and I want to create a solution which is generic, finds all img, iframe in ngInclude, uiView and can selectively lazy load in any element to which it is applied.

Comment: Ok still not convinced a directive is the optimal way. A service is considered reusable too, anyway, ng-include provides an onload event if necessary.

Comment: Hey, the onload thing did the trick, it actually emits an event $includeContentLoaded for each ng-include. Thanks for that. You can rephrase the answer with this solution and I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. Updated my answer. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, ng-include will include the element after the directive's link function. It will depend on the structure of your app and what you're trying to achieve, but essentially (via timeout, or promises, or callbacks), you need to have a mechanism to determine when your DOM is in a stable state (ng-includes may have more ng-includes etc and it can get complex), and then run your directive logic after that.

Comment: Yes I got that part. now figuring out how to wait until all partials everywhere have been loaded.

Comment: There is no quick fix solution for that, it depends on your business logic and you need to hook it up manually (consider nested templates that wait on async requests)

Comment: I was kind of creating a general reusable directive that could apply anywhere. Looks like a lot of cases need to be considered. Thanks for your input.